# How to output prettified raw HTML code inside an Editable DIV

Tags: javascript, html, pretty-print

I have been trying to output raw HTML inside an editable DIV, but the `<div>` gets commented out.

This is what I am trying to output *(Including the ***``***) :*

```
\`<div class="flexContainer">HELLO WORLD</div>\`
```

This is what I get instead (*Please NOTE* **`HELLO WORLD`** *is not wrapped inside a div*) :

```
`HELLO WORLD`;
```

**THE CALL**

```
let htmlCode = `\`<div class="flexContainer">HELLO WORLD</div>\`;`;
document.getElementById(myEditableDIVInputArea_Id).innerHTML = js_beautify(<pre><code>${htmlCode}</code></pre>);
```

How can I get the raw HTML output?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: dont use `innerHTML` cuz its gonna output the element instead of the div tag string

Answer (score 2):

You can insert them as Text instead of HTML

```js
let htmlCode = `\`<div class="flexContainer">HELLO WORLD</div>;\``
document.getElementById('x').innerText = htmlCode;
```

```html
<div id=x contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: btw he wants to output `\`<div class="flexContainer">HELLO WORLD</div>\`` with the `

Comment: @Anonymouse thanks. miss the *(Including the ``)* part

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev it looks like you can invoke `highlightElement` after insert the code. (not sure about that library, but shouldn't the formatted code output be valid HTML itself at first?)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}

let htmlCode = escapeHtml('<div class="flexContainer">HELLO WORLD</div>')
document.getElementById(myEditableDIVInputArea_Id).innerHTML = js_beautify(<pre><code>${htmlCode}</code></pre>);
```